# Stack rasters and calculate each pixel's max value then keep that value for rest of the layers in R

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have 181 daily rasters stacked. I want to find peak for each pixel and then assign peak value to the rest. Original Data Curve:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

This result is for single pixel.

This is what I tried using raster package.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(ncols=5, nrows=5)
set.seed(0)
r1 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r2 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r3 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r4 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r5 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))

a <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
a[c(1,2,3,22,23,24,25)] <- NA

b <- a

for (j in 1:ncell(a)) {
  x <- a[j]
  if(!is.na(x[1])){
    y <- which.max(x)
    b[j][y:nlayers(a)] <- x[y]
  }
}
```

I figured out a way to ignore NA's. This works fine on 24 cells 181 layers. But when I apply it on 28,000 cells 181 layers it takes 1hr on a pretty decent machine. (Xeon processor, 64GB Ram, 16GB GPU, win10 64bit). I understand terra is better, but I can't translate same code in terra.
Hers's what I tried to do in terra

```
library(terra)

a <- b <- terra::rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, nl=5, vals=NA)
set.seed(0)
values(a) <- runif(size(a))
a[c(1,2,3,22,23,24,25)] <- NA

b <- a

for (j in 1:ncell(a)) {
  x <- a[j]
  if(!is.na(x[1])){
    y <- which.max(x)
    b[j][y:nlyr(a)] <- x[y]
  }
}
```

But output is same as input.

Comment: Could you just take the max value, and then apply that to all subsequent dates from the date that max value appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to adjust Colin's function to take care of NAs

```
f_max <- function(x) {
    if (!is.na(x[1])) {
        i <- which.max(x)
        x[i:length(x)] <- x[i]
    }
    x
}
b <- app(a, f_max)
```

If you wanted the curve to never go down, you could use `terra::cummax`

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=30)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- runif(size(r))
```

Solution

```
x <- cummax(r)
```

Illustrated for four cells

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=rep(2,4))
for (i in c(2,3,8,9)) {
  plot(unlist(r[i]))
  lines(unlist(x[i]), col="blue", lwd=2)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This function is great too, but I need to make values static from max value onwards. I've updated original question too with reproducible code. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Professor. This works fine. Ill check it on original data. And in future I might have to apply it on whole Landsat Scenes. So that's why I'm optimizing my code. Thanks again, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For processing raster data, I would recommend using the `terra` package. It is an update to the `raster` package that is faster and in most cases easier to use (you can install it with `install.packages('terra')`). `terra` has a set of `apply` functions that allow you to apply functions over each stack of pixels. In the example below, I create a 2x2 pixel raster with some dummy data, and use the `terra::app` function to carry out the process you outline in your question:

```r
# Create random data for 181 rasters.
x = seq(-0, 10, length.out=181)

# `dnorm` can be used to simulate a bell curve, like the NDVI data. 
vals = rep(dnorm(x, 5, 1), 4)

# I couldn't get the raster to reshape correctly so I am just taking the first
# 50 values so the data are a nice bell curve. 
arr <- array(vals, dim = c(2, 2, 50)) 

# Replace this with your data. From your code, you can just use:
# bn <- terra::rast(fn)
r <- terra::rast(arr)

# Define a custom function that operates on one stack of pixels at a time.
fill_max <- function(timeseries) {
  
  # Find the index with the max value
  idx = which.max(timeseries)
  
  # Set all values past the max to the max value
  timeseries[idx:length(timeseries)] <- timeseries[idx]
  
  return(timeseries)
}

# Apply the function to the raster.
out <- terra::app(r, fun=fill_max)

# Check that process worked. Take the timeseries of the first pixel. 
vals <- terra::values(out)[1,]
# Plot the timeseries. 
plot(1:length(vals), vals)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. This function works fine but I'm unable to handle NA's. Tried na.omit(idx) but gives error. Any idea how to go about that. I've updated original question too with reproducible code. Please have a look.